# When installing a new software repository, is it required to check the repository key fingerprint?

Tags: linux, gnupg, trust

I'm recording a video about installing some software from a vendor repository. At some point, I download the GPG key for the remote repository and check manually its fingerprint *before* adding key and the new repository to the list of trusted repositories for the current host:

```
REPO="https://download.docker.com/linux/debian"
# Download and check GPG key
# Expected fingerprint:
# 9DC8 5822 9FC7 DD38 854A E2D8 8D81 803C 0EBF CD88
curl -fsSL "${REPO}/gpg" > docker.debian.gpg
gpg --no-option \
    --with-fingerprint --keyid-format LONG \
    docker.debian.gpg
```

And only if the fingerprint matches, I continue the process:

```
# Add Docker repository
apt-key add docker.debian.gpg
add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] ${REPO} \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable"
```

(the code above is for Debian, but I follow the same pattern for CentOS/RedHat)

I *feel* like checking the key fingerprint is an important step to ensure we will not install a software from a subverted repository. But I'm not quite sure of myself: some other tutorials I saw seem to actually assume the repository key will be *automagically* checked at a later time.

So, in such case, what extra layer of security does that add to check the key fingerprint? What would be the risks of *not* doing that?

Answer (score 2):

*[I'm not an expert on `apt` or `yum/dnf`, so this is just an opinion.]*

> some other tutorials I saw seem to actually assume the repository key will be automagically checked at a later time.

Checked against what? Against the same repository that gave it to you in the first place? If this happens to be a malicious repo, of course it's going to continue to tell you it's the real thing. There's no magic list somewhere of which keys are authentic for which repos. Well, actually there is, the list that ships with `apt`, but you're explicitly telling `apt` to modify that list.

My understanding of `add-apt-repository` is that once you add it, this *becomes an anchor of trust* against which to check all future signatures from this source. If it is malicious, then once you insert it into your trusted keys list you are open to receiving malicious / spoofed software from that developer.

---

### Establishing trust

The real question is: where are you getting this from?

```
# Expected fingerprint
# 9DC8 5822 9FC7 DD38 854A E2D8 8D81 803C 0EBF CD88
```

If you got it from the same source that will be serving you the packages, or from a non-encrypted HTTP page, or from some sketchy blog, then that's not doing you much good.

Ideally you want to be getting the fingerprint "out of band", ie from a different source that you already have real-world trust in.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Mike!

_"My understanding of add-apt-repository is that once you add it, this becomes an anchor of trust"_ It was mostly my understanding too. From what I read, this is the exact purpose of "apt-add key" to add an anchor or trust. But I can't find confirmation.

_"Ideally you want to be getting the fingerprint "out of band", ie from a different source that you already have real-world trust in."_ That's another reason I find that useful to add to my video. That later would become another *independent* source to check the fingerprint against. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Yup, but somebody getting the fingerprint from your video is only useful if it's the right fingerprint ;)